# Proved Lemma $3.5$ from the paper $I^K$-convergence by Macaj & Sleziak ; need it checked

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, filters

[$I^K$ *Convergence* by Sleziak & Macaj](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/papers/IKconv2.pdf)

**Lemma $3.5$**. If $I$ and $K$ are ideals on a set $S$ and $f : S → X$ is a function such that   $K\lim f = x$,then $I^K \lim f = x$.

I've done the proof I need it checked for correctness::

***proof:*** Take any $M\in \mathcal F(I)$. Define $$ g(s) =
\begin{cases}
f(s),  & s\in M \\
x, & s\notin M
\end{cases}$$

To show $K \lim g=x$ we have to show $$g^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal F(K)$$

Now $$g^{-1}(U)=\{s\in S:g(s)\in U\}\\ \subset \left(\left(\{s\in S: f(s)\in U\}\right)\cap M \right)\cup \{s\in S: s\notin S\}\\ \subset\{s\in S:f(s)\in U\}\cup (S\backslash M)\\ \in \mathcal f(K) $$ because $\{s\in S : f(s)\in U\}\in \mathcal F(K)$ and $\mathcal F(K)$ being a filter, contains the supersets of its members.

Hence we have $K\lim g=x$ implying $I^k \lim f=x$(proved)

Thank you.

> The necessary Definitions :

$I$-**Convergence** :Let $I$ be an ideal on a set $S$ and $X$ be a topological space. A function $f : S → X$  is said to be $I$-convergent to $x ∈ X$ if
$f^{−1}(U)=\{s ∈ S; f(s) ∈ U\} ∈ \mathcal F(I)$ holds for every neighborhood $U$ of the point $x$.
We use the notation $I- \lim f = x$.

$I^K$-**Convergence**: Let $K$ and $I$ be ideals on a set $S$, let $X$ be a topological space and let $x$ be an element of $X$. The function $f : S → X$ is said to be $I^K$-convergent to $x$ if there exists a set $M ∈ \mathcal F(I)$ such that the function $g : S → X$ given by
$$ g(s) =
\begin{cases}
f(s),  & s\in M \\
x, & s\notin M
\end{cases}$$
is $K$-convergent to $x$. If $f$ is $I^K$-convergent to $x$, then we write $I^K \lim f = x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of $\mathcal I^{\mathcal K}$ convergence says that there **exists** a set $M\in\mathcal F(\mathcal I)$ such that $f$ is $\mathcal K$-convergent "along" $M$.

To prove the above lemma, you can simply take $M=S$. In this case you get $g=f$ and thus you immediately have that $g$ is $\mathcal K$-convergent.

---

You made things slightly more difficult in that you are trying to prove the same thing for **every** $M\in\mathcal F(\mathcal I)$. (However, this is still true - if it is $\mathcal K$-convergent on $S$, the same will be true for $\mathcal K$-convergence "along" subsets.)

Your proof seems to contain some typos and minor mistakes, but if you realize that the inclusions you wrote are actually equalities and you have
\begin{align*}
g^{-1}(U) &= \{s\in S; g(s)\in U\}\\
&= (\{s\in S; f(s)\in U\}\cap M) \cup (S\setminus M)\\
&= \{s\in S; f(s)\in U\} \cup (S\setminus M)\\
&= f^{-1}(U) \cup (S\setminus M)
\end{align*}
then you get that $g^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal F(\mathcal K)$.

The way your proof is currently presented it contains some typos and minor problems. Here is quote from the [current revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2012393/1) of your post:

> Now $$g^{-1}(U)=\{s\in S:g(s)\in U\}\\ \subset \left(\left(\{s\in S: f(s)\in U\}\right)\cap M \right)\cup \{s\in S: s\notin S\}\\ \subset\{s\in S:f(s)\in U\}\cup (S\backslash M)\\ \in \mathcal f(K) $$ because $\{s\in S : f(s)\in U\}\in \mathcal F(K)$ and $\mathcal F(K)$ being a filter, contains the supersets of its members.

Some things seem to be obvious typos (but I decided not to correct them myself - since you asked for critique of your proof, maybe it is better not to edit it in places where this could change the intended meaning):

- You probably wanted to write $\{s\in S: s\notin M\}$ instead of $\{s\in S: s\notin S\}$.
- You probably wanted to write $\mathcal F(K)$ instead of $\mathcal f(K)$.

The main problem is that you want to show that $g^{-1}(U)$ is a *superset* of some set from the filter. Instead what you wrote is that it is a *subset* of a set from the filter. (But since the inclusions you wrote are in fact equalities, this can be easily corrected.)

Comment: $\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\bigcap M=f^{-1}(U) ?$ May be there are some points in $s_0\in S\backslash M$ such that usually $f(s_0)\in U$ for $g(s)$ that point is not being condidered- $g(s_0)=x$ and $g(s)=f(s)$ only if $s\in M.$  I thought that is what the definition meant. I made it a subset instead of a superset which makes the whole proof absurd just their equality does not seem easy.

Comment: Oh,I get it now. It's not necessarily $\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\bigcap M= f^{-1}(U).$ It is $\left(((f^{1}(U))\bigcap M\right)\cup (S\backslash M)=(f^{1}(U))\cup (S\backslash M).$ The $s_0$ I found above will go into $S\backslash M.$